# Problem in laravel query syntaxes with 'join' line

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have an inexplicable syntaxe error in my laravel query.

My query in php:

```php
$data['bassin'] = DB::table('previsionrdt.rdt', 'previsionrdt.bc')
    ->select ('id_bc', DB::raw('SUM(surf_rpg17) as sum_surf'))
    ->from ('previsionrdt.rdt', 'p')
    ->join ('previsionrdt.bc', 'c', 'on', 'c.gid', '=', 'p.id_bc')
    ->groupBy ('id_bc')
    ->get();
```

My query in pgAdmin :

```
select id_bc, sum(surf_rpg17) as sum_surf
from previsionrdt.rdt p
join previsionrdt.bc c on c.gid = p.id_bc
group by id_bc
```

When I test the code it says that they is a syntaxe error on the join line and I don't know where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this

```
        ->join('previsionrdt.bc as c', 'c.gid', '=', 'p.id_bc')
```

Comment: I tested your code, he doesn't work. I have the same error.

Comment: Ah I see you have another one in the beginning 
`DB::table('previsionrdt.rdt', 'previsionrdt.bc') `
should be 
`DB::table('previsionrdt.rdt as p')`

Comment: I tested it, it's  working, thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
$data['bassin'] = DB::table('previsionrdt.rdt', 'previsionrdt.bc')
    ->select ('id_bc', DB::raw('SUM(surf_rpg17) as sum_surf'))
    ->from ('previsionrdt.rdt', 'p')
    ->join('previsionrdt.bc as c', 'c.gid', '=', 'p.id_bc')
    ->groupBy ('id_bc')
    ->get();
```